# SQL Sever: in...case...in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql, select, case, where-clause

I need to code up a query for something like this:

```
Select [something]
Where
condition in
case
when (if another_condition = A and 3rd Condition = B) then (C,D)
when (if another_condition = N and 3rd Condition = E) then (F,G)
else (J,K)
end
```

essentially, what I want is if A and B are met, condition could be set to either C or D, if N or E are met, then condition could be set to F or G, else condition set to J or K.
However, when I run this, I kept getting
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Case'.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'set to either C or D' in your CASE statement? You can't have 2 different results from the same CASE condition being met.

Comment: To get around the CASE error, put the CASE statement in brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
Where  (Another_Condition = 'A' And Third_Condition = 'B' And Condition in ('C','D'))
       Or 
       (Another_Condition = 'N' and Third_Condition = 'E' And Condition in ('F','G'))
       Or 
       Condition In ('J','K')
```

Be very careful about mixing and's and or's in a where clause.  Parenthesis are important.

Comment: I was going to suggest this too. I think your final OR clause is wrong though, since it will test Condition IN ('J', 'K') for every row, unlike the CASE ... ELSE which will only test it for rows that didn't match the first two clauses.

The final line should read:

NOT ((Another_Condition = 'A' AND Third_Condition = 'B') OR (Another_Condition = 'N' AND Third_Condition = 'E')) AND Condition IN ('J', 'K')

Answer (score 1):

How about this - the UNION subquery will give you the full result set within the subquery. Then you can say 'WHERE condition IN ' (subquery). Like this:

```
SELECT [something]
WHERE
condition IN
(SELECT CASE WHEN (another_condition = A AND 3rd Condition = B) THEN C
   WHEN (another_condition = N AND 3rd Condition = E) THEN F
   ELSE J
   END AS Value

UNION

SELECT CASE WHEN (another_condition = A AND 3rd Condition = B) THEN D
   WHEN (another_condition = N AND 3rd Condition = E) THEN G
   ELSE K
   END AS Value
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to everyone's answer, I used G Mastro's approach and it worked great! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably go with G Mastro's approach of expanding the query as a Boolean expression. While the nested query approach will work, the intent of the code is less obvious IMO.

Having said that, if there are a lot of cases in your CASE statement, you may want to consider reshaping your data, because no matter how you write the query, it boils down to a big Boolean expression.